# System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer throws exception Argument cannot be null

Tags: c#, json, mono

We are building an application that runs under Xamarin and we have some common code that is shared amongst Android, iOS, and just plain mono running on a RaspberryPi.  The code is a wrapper around the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer and simply handles converting a class to and from a JSON string.  This code works fine under Windows using .Net 4.5.2 (that is the highest version we can use on the PI which runs mono 3.2.8).

The problem is that when we call the serializer, we get a System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null  Parameter name: rootName.

Well, our object is a plain old class that does not have a "rootName" node which looks suspiciously like it is thinking we are Xml, not Json.

We cannot use Newtonsoft because when dealing with a complex class, it calls an "emitter" which iOS does not allow, so we dropped back to the .Net Json serializer.

Everything works fine when we use Newtonsoft (PI and Android), but the iOS is keeping us from that platform.

Attached is a console app that faithfully recreates the problem on the PI.  It runs just fine in Windows, and also on our Android.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace TestSerialization
{
    #region Program
    /// <summary>
    /// Class Program - this is the entry point.
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        #region Main
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the entry point of the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestThis();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        #endregion

        #region TestThis
        /// <summary>
        /// Tests the various scenarios
        /// </summary>
        private static void TestThis()
        {
            try
            {
                //
                // Build the test objects
                //
                ClassWithNoConstructor classWithNoConstructor = new ClassWithNoConstructor { Int01 = 1, Int02 = 2, String01 = "hello01", String02 = "world02", OtherClass01 = new EmbeddedClass { OC01 = "OCString01", OC02 = "OCString02" } };
                ClassWithConstructorForStrings classWithConstructorForStrings = new ClassWithConstructorForStrings("hello03", "world04") { Int01 = 3, Int02 = 4, OtherClass01 = new EmbeddedClass { OC01 = "OCString03", OC02 = "OCString04" } };
                ClassWithEmptyConstructor classWithEmptyConstructor = new ClassWithEmptyConstructor();
                classWithEmptyConstructor.Int01 = 5;
                classWithEmptyConstructor.Int02 = 6;
                classWithEmptyConstructor.String01 = "hello05";
                classWithEmptyConstructor.String02 = "world06";
                classWithEmptyConstructor.OtherClass01 = new EmbeddedClass();
                classWithEmptyConstructor.OtherClass01.OC01 = "OCString05";
                classWithEmptyConstructor.OtherClass01.OC02 = "OCString06";
                try
                {
                    string json = JsonHelper.Serialize(classWithNoConstructor, false);
                    Console.WriteLine(">>> {0} <<<",classWithNoConstructor.GetType().Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("NewtonSoft  : {0}", json);
                    json = JsonHelper.Serialize(classWithNoConstructor, true);
                    Console.WriteLine("DataContract: {0}", json);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                try
                {
                    string json = JsonHelper.Serialize(classWithConstructorForStrings, false);
                    Console.WriteLine(">>> {0} <<<", classWithConstructorForStrings.GetType().Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("NewtonSoft  : {0}", json);
                    json = JsonHelper.Serialize(classWithConstructorForStrings, true);
                    Console.WriteLine("DataContract: {0}", json);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                try
                {
                    string json = JsonHelper.Serialize(classWithEmptyConstructor, false);
                    Console.WriteLine(">>> {0} <<<", classWithEmptyConstructor.GetType().Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("NewtonSoft  : {0}", json);
                    json = JsonHelper.Serialize(classWithEmptyConstructor, true);
                    Console.WriteLine("DataContract: {0}", json);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                ShowComparison<ClassWithNoConstructor>(classWithNoConstructor);
                ShowComparison<ClassWithConstructorForStrings>(classWithConstructorForStrings);
                ShowComparison<ClassWithEmptyConstructor>(classWithEmptyConstructor);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ShowComparison
        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the comparison between Newtonsoft and the Data Contract serializer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the data you are comparing</typeparam>
        /// <param name="data">The data object you wish to compare.</param>
        private static void ShowComparison<T>(object data)
        {
            //
            // Show them as strings, deserialize them and show if they deserialized correctly
            //
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            bool isTheSameNS = false;
            bool isTheSameDC = false;
            Type typeOfTheData = data.GetType();

            bool DataContractFlag = false;
            string jsonNS = JsonHelper.Serialize(data, DataContractFlag);
            T deserializedNS = JsonHelper.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonNS, DataContractFlag);

            DataContractFlag = true;
            string jsonDC = JsonHelper.Serialize(data, DataContractFlag);
            T deserializedDC = JsonHelper.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonDC, DataContractFlag);

            if (typeOfTheData == typeof(ClassWithNoConstructor))
            {
                isTheSameNS = ((ClassWithNoConstructor)data).IsEqualTo(deserializedNS as ClassWithNoConstructor);
                isTheSameDC = ((ClassWithNoConstructor)data).IsEqualTo(deserializedDC as ClassWithNoConstructor);
            }
            else if (typeOfTheData == typeof(ClassWithConstructorForStrings))
            {
                isTheSameNS = ((ClassWithConstructorForStrings)data).IsEqualTo(deserializedNS as ClassWithConstructorForStrings);
                isTheSameDC = ((ClassWithConstructorForStrings)data).IsEqualTo(deserializedDC as ClassWithConstructorForStrings);
            }
            else if (typeOfTheData == typeof(ClassWithEmptyConstructor))
            {
                isTheSameNS = ((ClassWithEmptyConstructor)data).IsEqualTo(deserializedNS as ClassWithEmptyConstructor);
                isTheSameDC = ((ClassWithEmptyConstructor)data).IsEqualTo(deserializedDC as ClassWithEmptyConstructor);
            }

            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("======== {0} ======================================================", typeOfTheData.Name));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("++++ NewtonSoft +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Json: {0}", jsonNS));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Does Serialized object match original? {0}", isTheSameNS));
            sb.AppendLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("++++ DataContract +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Json: {0}", jsonDC));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Does Serialized object match original? {0}", isTheSameDC));
            sb.AppendLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Does DataContract Json Match Newtownsoft Json? {0}", jsonNS.Equals(jsonDC)));
            sb.AppendLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }

        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    #region JsonHelper
    /// <summary>
    /// Class JsonHelper.  Wraps different ways to convert models to and from Json
    /// </summary>
    public static class JsonHelper
    {
        #region Serialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the specified model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">The model that you wish to serialize.</param>
        /// <param name="useDataContract">if set to <c>true</c> use the DataContractSerializer.</param>
        /// <returns>System.String.</returns>
        public static string Serialize(object model, bool useDataContract = false)
        {
            if (useDataContract)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true };
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(model.GetType(), settings);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    js.WriteObject(ms, model);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region DeserializeObject
        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="json">The json string you wish to deserialize.</param>
        /// <param name="useDataContract">if set to <c>true</c> use the DataContractSerializer.</param>
        /// <returns>T.</returns>
        public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json, bool useDataContract = false)
        {
            if (useDataContract)
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
                {
                    T result = (T)js.ReadObject(ms);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            }
        } 
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    #region ClassWithEmptyConstructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Class ClassWithEmptyConstructor - Just another test case to be sure a "default empty" contstructor still works.
    /// </summary>
    public class ClassWithEmptyConstructor
    {
        public ClassWithEmptyConstructor() { }
        public int Int01 { get; set; }
        public int Int02 { get; set; }
        public string String01 { get; set; }
        public string String02 { get; set; }
        public string ReadOnly { get { return "ReadOnly03"; } }

        public EmbeddedClass OtherClass01 { get; set; }

        public bool IsEqualTo(ClassWithEmptyConstructor other)
        {
            if ((other.Int01 == this.Int01)
                && (other.Int02 == this.Int02)
                && (other.String01 == this.String01)
                && (other.String02 == this.String02)
                && (other.OtherClass01.Equals(this.OtherClass01)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    #region ClassWithNoConstructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Class ClassWithNoConstructor - just a plain class to be initialized by the calling program.
    /// </summary>
    public class ClassWithNoConstructor
    {
        public int Int01 { get; set; }
        public int Int02 { get; set; }
        public string String01 { get; set; }
        public string String02 { get; set; }
        public string ReadOnly { get { return "ReadOnly01"; } }
        public EmbeddedClass OtherClass01 { get; set; }

        public bool IsEqualTo(ClassWithNoConstructor other)
        {
            if ((other.Int01 == this.Int01)
                && (other.Int02 == this.Int02)
                && (other.String01 == this.String01)
                && (other.String02 == this.String02)
                && (other.OtherClass01.Equals(this.OtherClass01)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    #region ClassWithConstructorForStrings
    /// <summary>
    /// Class ClassWithConstructorForStrings - a data class with a constructor that takes two strings
    /// and also an empty constructor because the DataContract serializer requires it. The Newtonsoft
    /// serializer does NOT require the empty constructor
    /// </summary>
    public class ClassWithConstructorForStrings
    {
        public ClassWithConstructorForStrings() { }
        public ClassWithConstructorForStrings(string s01, string s02) { String01 = s01; String02 = s02; }
        public int Int01 { get; set; }
        public int Int02 { get; set; }
        public string String01 { get; set; }
        public string String02 { get; set; }
        public string ReadOnly { get { return "ReadOnly02"; } }
        public EmbeddedClass OtherClass01 { get; set; }

        public bool IsEqualTo(ClassWithConstructorForStrings other)
        {
            if ((other.Int01 == this.Int01)
                && (other.Int02 == this.Int02)
                && (other.String01 == this.String01)
                && (other.String02 == this.String02)
                && (other.OtherClass01.Equals(this.OtherClass01)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    #region EmbeddedClass
    /// <summary>
    /// Class EmbeddedClass - used to test a complex class serialization
    /// This fails in NewtonSoft / Xamarin / iOS because it calls a CodeEmitter which apparently iOS does not allow.
    /// </summary>
    public class EmbeddedClass
    {

        public string OC01 { get; set; }
        public string OC02 { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            EmbeddedClass other = (EmbeddedClass)obj;
            if (other.OC01 == OC01 && other.OC02 == OC02)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    } 
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` inherits from [`XmlObjectSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xmlobjectserializer.aspx) under the hood, and uses a [specialized XML writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory_methods.aspx) to write JSON.  So the exception you are seeing is plausible.  Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message, and traceback?

Comment: hmmm in the worst case, you'll have code like this : `if(platform.ios){use .Net serializer} else {use NewtonSoft}`, I hope someone gives you better than this :)

Comment: I am going to suggest you try the following:  1) Allocate your serializer by doing `new DataContractJsonSerializer(model.GetType())` -- i.e. don't use `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`.  Does this solve the problem?  2)  Allocate using settings, but do `var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true, RootName = "root" };`.  Does setting the [`RootName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.rootname.aspx) explicitly solve the problem?

Comment: Basically we are doing a "if iOS then use DataContract else use Newtonsoft.  The optional parameter we pass in to our helper is specifically for that purpose.  However, we want to create a general use SDK and do not want to make our consumers deal with that (that is why we default to using Newtonsoft).  Also, we first did this without the DataContractJsonSerializerSettings, and we got the same result.  We tried adding the "root" as you suggested, but that throws a different exception.   Newtonsoft works great, but we cannot use it with iOS.

Comment: I only get the exception on the PI that is running mono.  I dont have access to that right now, but on Monday I will try to get the whole stack trace.

Comment: @twreynol - please also add the exception you get when `RootName` is explicitly set.  Also, are you willing to build your own copy of Json.NET from the [source tree](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)?  If so, you could modify [`JsonTypeReflector.DynamicCodeGeneration`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L398) to return `false` and see if that works on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the suggestions above, I tried the following in my Json helper:

```
 #region Serialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the specified model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">The model that you wish to serialize.</param>
        /// <param name="useDataContract">if set to <c>true</c> use the DataContractSerializer.</param>
        /// <returns>System.String.</returns>
        public static string Serialize(object model, bool useDataContract = false)
        {
            if (useDataContract)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true, RootName = "root", MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 1000 };
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(model.GetType(), settings);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    js.WriteObject(ms, model);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

That seems to have fixed the problem.  For the curious, attached are the two stack traces from the PI that were asked for earlier (along with the final version that actually worked.)  Thanks all!

```
=========== Stack Trace #1 =====================

Code:
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true };
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(model.GetType(), settings);


System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: rootName
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.String rootName, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes, Int32 maxItemsInObjectGraph, Boolean ignoreExtensionDataObject, Boolean alwaysEmitTypeInformation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.String rootName, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes, Int32 maxItemsInObjectGraph, Boolean ignoreExtensionDataObject, IDataContractSurrogate dataContractSurrogate, Boolean alwaysEmitTypeInformation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at TestSerialization.JsonHelper.Serialize (System.Object model, Boolean useDataContract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at TestSerialization.Program.TestThis () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

=========== Stack Trace #2 =====================

Code:
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true, RootName="root" };
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(model.GetType(), settings);


System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error during serialization for object of type TestSerialization.ClassWithNoConstructor ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The object graph exceeded the maximum object count '0' specified in the serializer
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializationWriter.WriteObjectContent (System.Object graph, Boolean top, Boolean outputTypeName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObjectContent (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at TestSerialization.JsonHelper.Serialize (System.Object model, Boolean useDataContract) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at TestSerialization.Program.TestThis () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

=========== Stack Trace #3 =====================

Code:
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true, RootName = "root", MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 1000 };
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(model.GetType(), settings);

>>> ClassWithNoConstructor <<<
NewtonSoft  : {"Int01":1,"Int02":2,"String01":"hello01","String02":"world02","ReadOnly":"ReadOnly01","OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString01","OC02":"OCString02"}}
DataContract: {"Int01":1,"Int02":2,"OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString01","OC02":"OCString02"},"String01":"hello01","String02":"world02"}
>>> ClassWithConstructorForStrings <<<
NewtonSoft  : {"Int01":3,"Int02":4,"String01":"hello03","String02":"world04","ReadOnly":"ReadOnly02","OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString03","OC02":"OCString04"}}
DataContract: {"Int01":3,"Int02":4,"OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString03","OC02":"OCString04"},"String01":"hello03","String02":"world04"}
>>> ClassWithEmptyConstructor <<<
NewtonSoft  : {"Int01":5,"Int02":6,"String01":"hello05","String02":"world06","ReadOnly":"ReadOnly03","OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString05","OC02":"OCString06"}}
DataContract: {"Int01":5,"Int02":6,"OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString05","OC02":"OCString06"},"String01":"hello05","String02":"world06"}

======== ClassWithNoConstructor ======================================================
++++ NewtonSoft +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Json: {"Int01":1,"Int02":2,"String01":"hello01","String02":"world02","ReadOnly":"ReadOnly01","OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString01","OC02":"OCString02"}}
Does Serialized object match original? True
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++ DataContract +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Json: {"Int01":1,"Int02":2,"OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString01","OC02":"OCString02"},"String01":"hello01","String02":"world02"}
Does Serialized object match original? True
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Does DataContract Json Match Newtownsoft Json? False
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

======== ClassWithConstructorForStrings ======================================================
++++ NewtonSoft +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Json: {"Int01":3,"Int02":4,"String01":"hello03","String02":"world04","ReadOnly":"ReadOnly02","OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString03","OC02":"OCString04"}}
Does Serialized object match original? True
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++ DataContract +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Json: {"Int01":3,"Int02":4,"OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString03","OC02":"OCString04"},"String01":"hello03","String02":"world04"}
Does Serialized object match original? True
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Does DataContract Json Match Newtownsoft Json? False
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

======== ClassWithEmptyConstructor ======================================================
++++ NewtonSoft +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Json: {"Int01":5,"Int02":6,"String01":"hello05","String02":"world06","ReadOnly":"ReadOnly03","OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString05","OC02":"OCString06"}}
Does Serialized object match original? True
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++ DataContract +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Json: {"Int01":5,"Int02":6,"OtherClass01":{"OC01":"OCString05","OC02":"OCString06"},"String01":"hello05","String02":"world06"}
Does Serialized object match original? True
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Does DataContract Json Match Newtownsoft Json? False
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```